# Rust Crossclip Print Type of Clipboard

Tags: rust

I'm trying to use the [crossclip](https://github.com/mcobzarenco/crossclip/tree/0cde8b4d5d106eab149cf7343f01ed737f8a3dad) crate to copy/paste images to/from the clipboard. The provided example of setting a string to the clipboard is simple enough:

```rust
use crossclip::{Clipboard, SystemClipboard, Result};

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let clipboard = SystemClipboard::new()?;
    clipboard.set_string_contents(String::from("Hello"))?;
    println!("{}", clipboard.get_string_contents()?);
}
```

get_string_contents returns a String. I'm assuming that to access in image in the clipboard I'll need the get_content method, described in the [documentation](https://docs.rs/crossclip/0.7.0/crossclip/x11/struct.X11Clipboard.html#method.get_contents) as:

```rust
fn get_contents(
    &self
) -> Result<(Vec<u8>, ClipboardContentType), ClipboardError>
```

How can I print out the type of the result from get_contents so I can see if its an image?

```rust
fn printTypeOfClipboardContents() -> Result<(), ClipboardError> {
    let clipboard = SystemClipboard::new()?;
    let teststuff = clipboard.get_contents();
    //print the type of teststuff
    Ok(())
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly underneath the documentation for [get_contents](https://docs.rs/crossclip/0.7.0/crossclip/x11/struct.X11Clipboard.html#method.get_contents) you can see it says:

> WARNING: Unimplemented, use get_string_contents

and if you click on the link to view the src, you can see the whole function is defined as:

```
fn get_contents(&self) -> Result<(Vec<u8>, ClipboardContentType), ClipboardError> {
    todo!("Unimplemented, use `get_string_contents`");
}
```

I conclude that this library does not yet support any way to access any type of data other than plain text.

Comment: I see. I can't seem to find a crate that enables copying images to the clipboard anywhere :/. any thoughts on an approach? @harmic